# How can I add textbox when click on comment link for each comment

Tags: jquery

I am able to create comment box with LIKE and COMMENT button using below code however I want to add another TEXTBOX when user click on COMMENT link.

How can I add another textbox when I click on COMMENT link in below code

```js
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#cbox").keypress(function(e){

var key=e.which;

if(key==13)
{
 var i=0;

$("#cbox").each(function(){

var data=$(this).val();


$("#cdv").append('<div style="background-color:gray">'+data+'</div>'+'<div>'+'<a href="#" id="link'+i+'" style="text-decoration:none;font-family:calibari;font-size:15px">Like</a>'+'&nbsp'+'&nbsp'+'<a href="#" id="cmnt'+i+'" style="text-decoration:none">Comment</a>'+'</div>');

});

i++;

}

});


});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="cbox" />

</br>
</br>
<div id="cdv" style="background-color:#FF00BF;height:auto;width:300px">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$("#cdv").append('<div style="background-color:gray">'+data+'</div>'+'<div>'+'<a href="#" id="link'+i+'" style="text-decoration:none;font-family:calibari;font-size:15px">Like</a>'+'&nbsp'+'&nbsp'+'<a href="#" id="cmnt'+i+'" style="text-decoration:none">Comment</a>'+'</div>');
```

to

```
 $("#cdv").append('<div style="background-color:gray">'+data+'</div>'+'<div>'+'<a href="#" id="link'+i+'" style="text-decoration:none;font-family:calibari;font-size:15px">Like</a>'+'&nbsp'+'&nbsp'+'<a href="#" id="cmnt'+i+'" style="text-decoration:none" class='comment-link'>Comment</a>'+'</div>');
```

Notice I appended class='comment-link'  to your link.

No we can attach a onlick handlder to each link using something like:

```
<script>
$(function(){
     $("body").on(".comment-link","click", function(){
           $(this).append("<input type='text' class='added-input'/>")
      });
});
<script>
```

Comment: Thanks.this code add textbox even I dont click on comment link.I want to add textbox when I click on comment link